# css background gradient

Tags: css

I understand that most background gradients are implemented by creating an image one-pixel wide and (say) 1000 pixels tall, and repeating the image along the x-axis.

What happens in that case if the page is more than 1000 pixels tall? Is there to make a background gradient that can cope with a page of any length?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Common practice is to declare the background color of your page to be the color of the bottom most pixel of your gradient image. So when the gradient is over, at least there is no hard cut.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [CSS3's support for gradients](http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Gradient/). However, this isn't supported by older browsers so you're stuck with fixed-height images.

Answer (score 0):

Just add background-position: fixed! And additionally you'll have to declare background color of your page to be the color of the bottom most pixel like Hyperboreus said.
CSS3 is a good option but compatibility may vary...

Answer (score 0):

You can make any-sized background image span the entire height of a web page and have a smooth transition.

Consider the [following jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/MnEnz/):

```
body {
    background: #000 url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnLYK.png) repeat-x center top;
}
```

I'm using the `background` [shorthand property](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background) to specify both the `background-color` and `background-image` properties into a single rule.

I could just as easily have written the following rules, accomplishing the same effect:

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnLYK.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: center top;
}
```

The [PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnLYK.png) itself is only 1 x 1,000 pixels (W x H) in size, but **will accommodate an area of unlimited width or height**.

The actual height of your image isn't significant — rather, **it's the bottom color of the image matched to the CSS background-color *combined with repeating* that enables the gradient to appear to continue forever**.

What makes this simple technique work, is to specify the bottom-most color in your image (`#000` in my example) as the `background-color` and allow the `background-image` to repeat horizontally along the X axis (`repeat-x`).

So when the background-image ends, the background-color takes over and ensures a smooth transition without a hard cut-off.

---

*To illustrate how this technique works, try replacing **#000** in the example with a different color, say **#ffc**, and you'll be able to see where the background image stops and the background color takes over.*

Answer (score 0):

@rjb:
After the 1000px has reached the png stops repeating- you'll only see black color but it will appear continuous since the bottom most pixel of the png is black.(of course you know this!)
So I'd suggest adding a background position fixed instead. So the gradient will seem never ending and black color will not span the rest of the page...
Ex:

```
body {
    background: #000 url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnLYK.png) repeat-x fixed;
}
```